# Yii2 custom component namespace

Tags: yii2, namespaces, aliases

I have a component class located in the following path:

> @backend/components/component-name/ComponentClass.php

and want to use default namespace for this class:

> namespace backend\components;

I've tried to set aliases in my `confing/main.php`:

```
...
'aliases' => [
    '@backend/components' => '@backend/components/component-name'
],
...
```

but I know that's wrong decision, because it's broke the namespace logic for the other classes located in `backend/components`.

How can I set the same namespace `backend\components` for both classes in `@backend/components` and `@backend/components/component-name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use composer autoloader for this task - it works fine even if you provide multiple possible paths for single class. Edit your `composer.json` `autoload` section to something like:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "backend\\": "backend/",
        "backend\\components\\": "backend/components/component-name/",
        ...
    }
},
```

And run in console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Make sure that you're loading composer autoloader in your `index.php`:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Could you explain why should we need to add `"backend\\": "backend/"`?

Comment: It allows to use Composer autoloader for whole `backend` namespace. You probably don't need it if you're using Yii autoloader for `backend` namespace, but Yii autoloader will be removed in Yii 2.1 and Composer autoloader is faster, so I suggest to move to Composer autoloader completely and declare all namespaces (`backend`, `common`, `frontend` etc) in `composer.json` `autoload`.